# Unable to git clone and change permission of directory

Tags: linux, terminal, directory, file-permissions

I am trying:

> `git clone https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-parts-git`

but it comes an error message:

> fatal: could not create work tree dir 'fritzing-parts': Permission denied

I have tried to fix the permission directory:

> `chmod -R a+x usr/share/fritzing`

But comes another error message:

> changing permission of 'usr/share/fritzing/': operation not permitted

Can someone tell me what's wrong and what should I do?

Comment: Did you tried using sudo before you command?

Comment: There is a chance that `/usr/share/fritzing` is owned by `root:root` and you are using `git clone` and `chmod` with your own user (and without `sudo` as @Wiliam pointed). Try `ls -ld /usr/share/fritzing` and check it. If that is the case, this won't work until you change ownership of the folder to your user.